# Error reading variable from a file Microsoft Visual C

Tags: c, visual-c++, file-io

So I am executing a code that reads values from a file and process them. The workable code is below, and I can provide the file too.

```
FILE *fp1, *fp2;
short input_filt=0, output_filt=-32767; 
unsigned short alpha = 23528, i=0;

fp1=fopen("sine1kHz.mat", "r");
if(fp1==NULL)
    return 0;
fp2=fopen("filter.mat", "w"); 

for (i=0; i<1024; i++)
{
    fscanf(fp1, "%d", &input_filt);
    output_filt=(output_filt*alpha)+(input_filt*(1-alpha)); 
    fprintf(fp2, "%d %d\n", input_filt, output_filt);
}

fclose(fp1);
fclose(fp2);

return 0;
```

So I debugged and the reading from the file is absolutely fine. So there are no problems while I am in the loop (no access to values non existent).
However, once I leave the loop the program crashes and Microsoft Visual Studio gives me this message:

"Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'input_filt' was corrupted."

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?
Thank you!

Comment: `fscanf(fp1, "%d", &input_filt)` is expecting an `int`, which `short input_filt` isn't. So the code is breaking something which doesn't become immediately apparent.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong format specifier for `scanf`.

The `%d` format specifier to `scanf` expects an `int *` argument, however you're passing in a `short *`.  Since a `short` is smaller than an `int` on your system, `scanf` will write past the memory used by `input_filt` when the value is read in.

You want to use `%hd` instead which tells it to expect a `short *`.

```
fscanf(fp1, "%hd", &input_filt);
```

Note that it isn't strictly necessary to use `%hd` for `printf` because a `short` value passed to a variadic function will be automatically *promoted* to `int`.

Comment: Oh right, thank you! fprintf doesn't complain but fscanf does. Thank you!